# Laravel 9 in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, null given

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a Laravel 9 project and I'm trying to add arrays of staff access passcodes but I keep getting this error every time I type in the correct passcode: **in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, null given**

Heres the code:

```
public function access(Request $request) 
{
    $access_pass = config('web.offlinePass');

    if (!in_array($request->pass, $access_pass))

        return back()->withErrors(['The password entered is incorrect!']);

    session()->put('admins_only', $request->pass);
    
    session()-save();

    return redirect()->route('website.dash.dash');
}
```

Comment: Your second parameter `$access_pass` in the `in_array` is `null`. Double check your web.php config.

Comment: here it is
'admins_only' => [
        'test'
     ],

Comment: From what I see, you would have to have `config/web.php` file and inside `return ['offlinePass' => ['array', 'of', 'values']];`.

Variable `admins_only` is used in session from what I see.

Comment: It works, now I got this error. Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\save()

Comment: That's a different issue. Check your route, looks like you didn't define it properly.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, but now I got this error: Route [website.dash.dash] not defined.

Answer (score 4):

Replace your array, which has the value null with an empty array. (of course only when it is null):

```
in_array($request->pass, $access_pass ?? [])
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure that the variable you are checking is an array, so you can verify it with `print_r($variable_name)` before checking code `in_array()`

Answer (score 0):

Pluck method return a collection, which is not an array.

```
$payaments = Equipment::where('vehicle_id', $id)->pluck('equipment_value')->toArray();
```

Comment: How does your answer relate to the question?

Comment: in this example the  **$access_pass = config('web.offlinePass');**   not array . you check by function **dd($access_pass);** , for that you need to change to array by function **toArray()** to check is in array or not